# ordered set inclusion

Tags: sequence, subset, order

Suppose I have a ordered set $A=\{2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3,4\}$ and $C=\{2,4,3\}$.
Is there any mathematica command whether $A\subset B$ gives true(or 1) but $A$ which is not a subset of $C$ gives false(or 0)?

I know `OrderedQ`, but that only gives `OrderedQ[{2, 3}] == True` and `OrderedQ[{3, 2}] == False`, so it was not that useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[subsequenceQ]
subsequenceQ = MemberQ[Subsequences[#2, Length @ #], #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
a = {2, 3} ; b = {2, 3, 4} ; c = {2, 4, 3};

subsequenceQ[a, b]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
subsequenceQ[a, c]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
subsequenceQ[a, {4, 2, 3, 5}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
ClearAll[subsequenceQ1, subsequenceQ2, subsequenceQ3]

subsequenceQ1 = MemberQ[Partition[#2, Length@#, 1], #] &;

subsequenceQ2 = MatchQ[#2, Flatten[{___, #, ___}]] &;

subsequenceQ3 = SequenceCases[#2, #] =!= {} &;
```

Comment: Wow good! Thanks today, I learn many things on mathematica from your answer!

Comment: @phy_math, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: What if I allow the order. I mean $\{2,3\}$ is in $\{2,5,4,3\}$. Then How I can modify your function? I post [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241832/ordered-set-inclusion-2) with a specific example