# ordered set inclusion 2

Tags: sorting, subset, order

Slightly change the previous question, [ordered set inclusion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241827/ordered-set-inclusion),

Now, consider $A=\{2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3,4,5\}, C=\{5,2,4,3\}$, Now I want to make element $\{2,3\}$ is in $B$ as well as $C$, what can be useful command for mathematica? [Here $\{3,2\}$ is not in $B$, $C$]

For example, given (for example) $A=\{ 3,4,5\}$ and set $B=\{9,8,3,2,4,7,5\}$,  want to make function which produce true. [Since the order $3,4,5$ is same with B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[orderedSubsetQ]
orderedSubsetQ = MemberQ[Subsets[#2, {Length @ #}], #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
a = {2, 3} ; b = {2, 3, 4, 5} ; c = {5, 2, 4, 3};

orderedSubsetQ[a, b]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
orderedSubsetQ[a, c]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
orderedSubsetQ[{3,2}, b]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
orderedSubsetQ[{3,2}, c]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
orderedSubsetQ[{3, 4, 5}, {9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 7, 5}]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
orderedSubsetQ[{4, 3, 5}, {9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 7, 5}]
```

> ```
>  False
> ```

You can also use

```
ClearAll[orderedSubsetQ2, orderedSubsetQ3, orderedSubsetQ4, orderedSubsetQ5]

orderedSubsetQ2 = MatchQ[#2, Riffle[#, ___, {1, -1, 2}]] &;

orderedSubsetQ3 = DeleteCases[#2, Except[Alternatives @@ #]] == # &;

orderedSubsetQ4 = SequenceCases[#2, Riffle[#, ___]] =!= {} &;

orderedSubsetQ5 = Positive @ SequenceCount[#2, Riffle[#, ___]] &;
```